# Jetty embedded running using OpenJDK throws PWC6188

Tags: java, jersey, jetty, jstl, embedded-jetty

I am running a web application that uses Jersey 1.19.4 and JSTL 1.2.

Here is the maven dependency tree for the Embedded jetty project.

```
    [INFO] +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-webapp:jar:9.4.14.v20181114:compile
    [INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-xml:jar:9.4.14.v20181114:compile
    [INFO] |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlet:jar:9.4.14.v20181114:compile
    [INFO] |     \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-security:jar:9.4.14.v20181114:compile
    [INFO] |        \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-server:jar:9.4.14.v20181114:compile
    [INFO] +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlets:jar:9.4.14.v20181114:compile
    [INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-continuation:jar:9.4.14.v20181114:compile
    [INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-http:jar:9.4.14.v20181114:compile
    [INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-util:jar:9.4.14.v20181114:compile
    [INFO] |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-io:jar:9.4.14.v20181114:compile
    [INFO] +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-jsp:jar:9.2.26.v20180806:compile
    [INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.jetty.toolchain:jetty-schemas:jar:3.1.M0:compile
    [INFO] |  +- javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:jar:3.1.0:compile
    [INFO] |  +- javax.servlet.jsp:javax.servlet.jsp-api:jar:2.3.1:compile
    [INFO] |  +- org.glassfish.web:javax.servlet.jsp:jar:2.3.2:compile
    [INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.jetty.orbit:javax.servlet.jsp.jstl:jar:1.2.0.v201105211821:compile
    [INFO] |  +- org.glassfish.web:javax.servlet.jsp.jstl:jar:1.2.2:compile
    [INFO] |  +- org.glassfish:javax.el:jar:3.0.0:compile
    [INFO] |  \- org.eclipse.jetty.orbit:org.eclipse.jdt.core:jar:3.8.2.v20130121:compile
    [INFO] +- org.eclipse.jetty.toolchain:jetty-jsp-jdt:jar:2.3.3:compile
    [INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.25:compile
    [INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.7.25:compile
    [INFO] +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.4:compile
    [INFO] +- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.3:compile
    [INFO] +- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.17:compile
    [INFO] \- log4j:apache-log4j-extras:jar:1.2.17:compile
```

**Error:**

```
    com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerException:
          org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /test.jsp(2,62) 
             PWC6188: The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core 
             cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application
```

Answer (score 0):

```
org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-jsp:jar:9.2.26.v20180806:compile
```

All versions of artifacts from `org.eclipse.jetty.*` should be the same version.

Upgrade the above one to `9.4.14.v20181114` too.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for the immediate reply.

I am using the GlassFish JSP Implementation and the most stable version that is available "org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-jsp:jar:9.2.26.v20180806:compile". 
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-jsp

I am running this embedded jetty program within Eclipse IDE 2018-09 using OpenJDK 11+28.

```
    java -version
    openjdk version "11" 2018-09-25
    OpenJDK Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11+28)
    OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11+28, mixed mode)
```

The same issue while using Oracle JDK as well.

```
    java -version
    java version "11.0.2" 2018-10-16 LTS
    Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.2+7-LTS)
    Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.2+7-LTS, mixed mode)
```

The application successfully works when I use Oracle JDK 1.8

In order to work in JDK 11, I have to change TLD URI in JSP page to well know name and then copy the tld's under WEB-INF directory and refer explicitly in web.xml file.

**JSP**(no error),

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="jstl-core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="jstl-functions" %>
```

**web.xml**

```
  <jsp-config>
    <taglib>
      <taglib-uri>jstl-core</taglib-uri>
      <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/c.tld</taglib-location>
    </taglib>
    <taglib>
      <taglib-uri>jstl-functions</taglib-uri>
      <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/fn.tld</taglib-location>
    </taglib>
  </jsp-config>
```

**Earlier JSP** (with error)

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>
```

I am not sure I am doing the right thing here, if anyone has right solution please let me know.

Comment: Glassfish JSP is unstable and highly buggy (far too many bugs present), that's why the Eclipse Jetty project switched to the Apache JSP project entirely.  Jetty 9.4.x is not compatible with Glassfish JSP and likely never will be again (it's far too old and incompatible with Servlet 3.1+ containers now)

Comment: The Eclipse Jetty project has JSP and JSTL tests for Java 1.8, 9, 10, 11, 12, and even the 13-ea JVMs.  Apache JSP is used for all of those JVMs.

Comment: Thanks, I will switch to Apache JSP and let you know the outcomes.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a Lot Joakim, after changing to apache-jsp it works great.  I have reverted back to use the URI in JSP.

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>
```

Here is my new dependency tree for the Jetty Embedded project,

```
+- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-webapp:jar:9.4.12.v20180830:compile
|  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-xml:jar:9.4.12.v20180830:compile
|  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlet:jar:9.4.12.v20180830:compile
|     \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-security:jar:9.4.12.v20180830:compile
|        \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-server:jar:9.4.12.v20180830:compile
+- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlets:jar:9.4.12.v20180830:compile
|  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-continuation:jar:9.4.12.v20180830:compile
|  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-http:jar:9.4.12.v20180830:compile
|  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-util:jar:9.4.12.v20180830:compile
|  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-io:jar:9.4.12.v20180830:compile
+- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-annotations:jar:9.4.12.v20180830:compile
|  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-plus:jar:9.4.12.v20180830:compile
|  |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-jndi:jar:9.4.12.v20180830:compile
|  +- javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:jar:1.2:compile
|  +- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:6.2:compile
|  \- org.ow2.asm:asm-commons:jar:6.2:compile
|     +- org.ow2.asm:asm-tree:jar:6.2:compile
|     \- org.ow2.asm:asm-analysis:jar:6.2:compile
+- org.eclipse.jetty:apache-jsp:jar:9.4.12.v20180830:compile
|  +- org.eclipse.jetty.toolchain:jetty-schemas:jar:3.1:compile
|  +- javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:jar:3.1.0:compile
|  \- org.mortbay.jasper:apache-jsp:jar:8.5.24.2:compile
|     +- org.mortbay.jasper:apache-el:jar:8.5.24.2:compile
|     \- org.eclipse.jdt:ecj:jar:3.12.3:compile
+- jstl:jstl:jar:1.2:compile
+- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.25:compile
+- org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.7.25:compile
```

I have also added the following in the embedded jetty server code,

```
//org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext
context.setAttribute("org.eclipse.jetty.server.webapp.ContainerIncludeJarPattern", ".*/[^/]*jstl.*\\.jar$");

org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.Configuration.ClassList classlist = org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.Configuration.ClassList.setServerDefault(server);
classlist.addAfter("org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.FragmentConfiguration","org.eclipse.jetty.plus.webapp.EnvConfiguration", "org.eclipse.jetty.plus.webapp.PlusConfiguration");
classlist.addBefore("org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.JettyWebXmlConfiguration","org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration");
```

Please let me know if any changes required with the above approach.